# Android Studio stacktrace is unclickable

Tags: java, android, debugging, ddms, clickable

Using : Android Studio (IntellIJ IDEA) running an Emulator

I want to be able to click on the stack-trace/error of the DDMS (Android Monitor) as shown here, to move to the file/line that caused this error.

[Unclickable stack trace](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xgitC.png)

Because of my last two unrelated questions I got banned for some years... So I hope that I respect every rules this time. Thank you.

Edit : apparently the Android Studio's Android Monitor is clickable, but not Android Studio's DDMS. Weird... Maybe because DDMS was made for Eclipse, not intellij idea.

[Android's DDMS is clickable](https://i.stack.imgur.com/g5UjH.png)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this using the 'Analyze Stacktrace` function.  This can be found on the menu:

`Analyze -> Analyze Stacktrace`

[image]

Just paste your stacktrace from DDMS into the dialog, click `OK` and it will give you one with clickable links (if it can find them).

Comment: Thanks for your answer, I just learned of this function. Is there no better way to do what I want? I just like how handy it was in Eclipse to click -> move to the line.

Comment: If you use the built in `Android Monitor` in Android studio then it automatically highlights the lines for you to click on.  Really there are almost no reasons to use DDMS these days. CMD+6 (on mac) will bring it up

Comment: Thanks for the answer :) Answered!